# How to invert 'watch -b'?

Tags: command-line, watch, bell

I'm trying to get my terminal to alert me with a simple bell once my domain registration has finished (is resolvable).

From `watch --help`:

> Options:
>   -b, --beep             beep if command has a non-zero exit

How can I invert this option, so it beeps if the command has a zero exit?
I also tried variations of the following, but I can't get it to beep when inside `watch`.

`watch 'nslookup foo.bar && echo "\a"'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since watch runs the command with `sh` by default (`-x` says not to run with `sh`), you can invert the return code with `!`:

```
watch -b ! nslookup foo.bar
```

Depending on your shell and config, you may need to quote `!`.

Answer (score 0):

My quick workaround now turned out to be this:

```
while (1); do nslookup foo.bar > /dev/null && echo "\a"; sleep 2; done
```